# How to add Multiple HTML files into the NSMutableArray?

Tags: iphone

Can anybody tell me how to add Multiple HTML files into the NSMutableArray?These HTML files exists in OtherSources folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me guess it:

Store all the html files as a string for each.
Then add the strings to the array and release the strings.

Thanks,
Bharath.